# Using slack API: "Module slack has no attribute WebClient "

Tags: python, slack-api

I try to use the slack API to send a message to a workspace, I found this piece of code on their docs but I have an issue with the module slack. This is the code I used:

```
import os
import slack

client = slack.WebClient(token=os.environ['SLACK_API_TOKEN'])

response = client.chat_postMessage(
    channel='#viktor',
    text="Hello world!")
assert response["ok"]
assert response["message"]["text"] == "Hello world!"
```

I have put my app token but it does not recognize `WebClient`... any idea?

Comment: The code looks correct. Are you sure you have the correct package and version installed? should be this: https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient

Comment: To upgrade to newest version do: `pip install slackclient --upgrade`

Comment: You can also run `pip show slackclient` to see what you got. Should be V2.1.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
pip install slack
pip install slackclient
```

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you don't have any user files named `slack` `slack_client`.
A simple filename change to something more original solved my problem.

This was my setup:

- MacOs HS
- Python 3.7
- latest (2.4) version of slackclient installed

Comment: will buy you a beer if knew who you are! thanks mate!

Comment: @Ignacio haha cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I use python-slack-sdk, it works great. See https://github.com/slackapi/python-slack-sdk#uploading-files-to-slack

To install, run
`pip3 install slack_sdk`

To upload a file

```
import os
from slack_sdk import WebClient
from slack_sdk.errors import SlackApiError

client = WebClient(token=os.environ['SLACK_BOT_TOKEN'])

try:
    filepath="./tmp.txt"
    response = client.files_upload(channels='#random', file=filepath)
    assert response["file"]  # the uploaded file
except SlackApiError as e:
    # You will get a SlackApiError if "ok" is False
    assert e.response["ok"] is False
    assert e.response["error"]  # str like 'invalid_auth', 'channel_not_found'
    print(f"Got an error: {e.response['error']}")
```